make diff ignore case of umlauts
I need to make diff ignore the case of my inputs.  Both inputs contain German umlauts like ä and Ä.  Option -i successfully makes diff ignore the case of my input for other characters like a and A, but not for umlauts:
$ diff -i <(echo ä) <(echo Ä)
1c1
< ä
---
> Ä

The output should be empty, as ä and Ä should be seen as the same letter if case is ignored.  If I try this instead:
$ diff -i <(echo a) <(echo A)

Then it works as expected (no output).
I also tried to set the environment variable LANG to make diff use the correct locale, but this didn’t seem to have any influence:
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 diff -i <(echo ä) <(echo Ä)

I tried various values for LANG.
Is there a way to make diff ignore the case of German umlauts?
(I’m on Ubuntu 22.04 FWIW.)

"I need to make diff ignore the case of my inputs" - Have fun coding that if the tool doesn't already do that.

-i is not a standard diff option - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html

GNU sed recognizes them (echo äa:ÄA  | sed  's/[[:lower:]]/\U&/g; s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/g'); GNU tr does not (echo äa:ÄA  | tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]')

@jhnc : Well, Gnu diff at least has -i, and since the OP uses Ubuntu, we can guess that he is using this.

@user1934428 true, I just pointed it out since "works as expected" will vary between implementations

I'm not really a Unicode specialist, but for my understanding, this is a bug in diff, and the normalization suggested by JosefZ should be done by diff itself. How about reporting this problem as a bug?

Fixed the tags for this question.

@user1934428 please see the updated answer…

Compare normalized strings, see Unicode normalization forms:
 diff -i <(echo ä| uconv -x Any-NFD) <(echo Ä| uconv -x Any-NFD)

Note: used uconv from sudo apt install icu-devtools
FYI:
Form   String StrLen Unicode
----   ------ ------ -------
NFC    äÄ          2 \u00e4\u00c4
NFD    äÄ          4 \u0061\u0308\u0041\u0308
NFKC   äÄ          2 \u00e4\u00c4
NFKD   äÄ          4 \u0061\u0308\u0041\u0308

Update:
from info diff [Emphasis mine]:

18.1.1 Handling Multibyte and Varying-Width Characters
‘diff’, ‘diff3’ and ‘sdiff’ treat each line of input as a string
of
unibyte characters.  This can mishandle multibyte characters in some cases.  For example, when asked to ignore spaces, ‘diff’ does
not properly ignore a multibyte space character.
Also, ‘diff’ currently assumes that each byte is one column wide,
and this assumption is incorrect in some locales, e.g., locales that
use UTF-8 encoding.  This causes problems with the ‘-y’ or
‘--side-by-side’ option of ‘diff’.
These problems need to be fixed without unduly affecting the
performance of the utilities in unibyte environments.
The IBM GNU/Linux Technology Center Internationalization Team has
proposed patches to support internationalized ‘diff’
(http://oss.software.ibm.com/developer/opensource/linux/patches/i18n/diffutils-2.7.2-i18n-0.1.patch.gz).
Unfortunately, these patches are incomplete and are to an older
version of ‘diff’, so more work needs to be done in this area.

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

I wondered about something like this, or iconv. Seems not to work in general though: e.g. æÆ / ðÐ / αΑ / аА / etc

@jhnc you are right; answer updated with a citation from info diff…

it's not just a GNU diff issue. busybox diff works with the question code but fails to process all characters correctly. eg: busybox diff -i <(echo äæðαа) <(echo ÄÆÐΑА) (assuming these are in fact the same string in lower and upper case)

I think the uconv normalisation approach only works for Latin characters (but is enough for handling umlauts).
The following code should allow diff -i to work with all UTF-8 upper or lowercase characters (Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, Adlam, etc):
case2ascii()(
    perl -CSD -pe '
        s/[[:lower:]]/c$&/g;
        s/[[:upper:]]/C\l$&/g;
    ' "$@"
)

ascii2case()(
    perl -CSD -pe '
        s{([cC])(.)}{ $1 eq "c" ? $2 : uc($2) }ge;
    ' "$@"
)

diff -i <(echo äæðαа | case2ascii) <(echo ÄÆÐΑА | case2ascii) | ascii2case


to encode:

convert each uppercase or lowercase letter to lowercase and prefix (escape) with an upper or lower c as appropriate


to decode:

find escape sequences and unescape, converting back to uppercase if necessary



GNU sed also appears to work:
case2ascii()(
    sed '
        s/[[:lower:]]/c&/g;
        s/[[:upper:]]/C\l&/g;
    ' "$@"
)

ascii2case()(
    sed '
        s/C\(.\)/\u\1/g;
        s/c\(.\)/\1/g;
    ' "$@"
)


the use of ascii in the name isn't really right since the output is not entirely ASCII - just the part that we expect diff to try to compare insensitively

Yes, I could lowercase the whole input.  But then the output also would be lowercased, so it does not show the original input anymore.  Instead of this, I just want to ignore case changes.

@Alfe ? the output is not lowercased - the ascii2case function undoes all the changes
